# how to update a row.value based on another row.value

Tags: swift, swift4, eureka-forms

I'm using a [Eureka form](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka), in which the user selects dates. When the user selects the first date, I want to update the second date in the second row (add 30 days to the first days).

```
        <<< DateRow(){
            $0.value = Date()
            $0.title = "First Date"
            $0.tag = "firstDate"
            .onChange({ (row) in
                << update secondDate = firstDate + 30 days >>
            } )

         <<< DateRow(){
            $0.value = Date()
            $0.title = "Second Date"
            $0.tag = "secondDate"
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find below solution.

```
func createSection() {
    let section = Section("Section2") { section in
        section.header?.height = { 40 }
    }

    <<< DateRow() {
        $0.value = Date()
        $0.title = "First Date"
        $0.tag = "First"
        }.onChange({ (row) in
            let secondRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "Second") as! DateRow
            let date = row.value!
            let newDate = date.addingTimeInterval(30*24*60*60)
            secondRow.value = newDate
            secondRow.reload()
        })

    <<< DateRow() {
        $0.value = Date()
        $0.title = "Second Date"
        $0.tag = "Second"
        }.onChange({ (row) in

        })

    form +++ section
}
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: @arakweker mark as right as well, it will be helpful to others